# Premissions to create files

Tags: files, permissions

I'm running Lamp and installing Wordpress.

I used:

```
chown -R personalusername:usergroup /var/www/html/wordpress
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/wordpress
```

But the wordpress can't create the config file using the browser interface.

But if I use:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/wordpress
```

...it creates the configuration file without problem.

Why does the second work and the first not. Why does it have to to be **chmod -R 777**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/var/www/*` works with `www-data:www-data` if you are on Ubuntu. So what you need to do is change the ownership to `www-data` and add yourself to that group using `usermod`:

```
usermod -aG www-data $USER
```

Comment: if I use chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress and use usermod -aG www-data $USER, the files stop being editable through the file navigator. I use mint.

Comment: only if I use chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/wordpress than all is editable. is this the right way?

Comment: no!! 777 is almost never the right way!

Comment: you need to logout+login again once you added a user to a group ..

Comment: @pLumo i've changed the permissions to 765 for read write within the group

Comment: In your case, `664` would probably be the right permission for files, `775` for directories.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96923/discussion-between-guerrier-and-plumo).